# Responsive "masonry-like" columns without using masonry (trying to avoid position:absolute;)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a layout of boxes that are all floated left and when you click on their headings, they slide open revealing content. The issue is that the way floats work, when you click to expand one of them, it messes with the row underneath.

http://jsfiddle.net/FCCye/ <-- click on one of the headings to see the issue.

I've solved this by separating them into columns like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/caW4M/

That works fine, however, the layout needs to be responsive, so when the window is 480 or lower, it needs to be 1 column. Between 480 and 768 it needs to be 2 columns. Anything above 768, 3 columns. (obviously, the jsfiddles don't show the breakpoints I have set up.)

This is the code I've come up with to solve this, however it is not working at all. I was wondering if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
// Create all three portfolio columns
    var one = $('<div/>').addClass('column').addClass('one');
    var two = $('<div/>').addClass('column').addClass('two');
    var three = $('<div/>').addClass('column').addClass('three');

    // Store all portfolio elements into variables once they're in columns
    var colElems = $('.column .project');

    // Now append the columns
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    if ( winWidth > 480 && winWidth <= 768 ) {

        // Remove everything from columns and delete existing columns
        $(colElems).appendTo('#portfolio .content');
        $('#portfolio .content').remove(one,two,three);

        // Store portfolio elements into variables for safe-keeping
        var c1Elems = $('.project:nth-child(2n+1)');
        var c2Elems = $('.project:nth-child(2n+2)');

        // Perform appends into portfolio columns
        c1Elems.appendTo(one);
        c2Elems.appendTo(two);

        // Append portfolio elements to columns     
        $('#portfolio .content').append(one,two);

    }else{

        // Remove everything from columns and delete existing columns
        $(colElems).appendTo('#portfolio .content');
        $('#portfolio .content').remove(one,two,three);

        // Store portfolio elements into variables for safe-keeping
        var c1Elems = $('.project:nth-child(3n+1)');
        var c2Elems = $('.project:nth-child(3n+2)');
        var c3Elems = $('.project:nth-child(3n+3)');

        // Perform appends into portfolio columns
        c1Elems.appendTo(one);
        c2Elems.appendTo(two);
        c3Elems.appendTo(three);

        $('#portfolio .content').append(one,two,three); 
    }
```

So, what I'm trying to do is append the normal 3 columns when it's not between 480 and 768 (because on mobile size, the columns would stack on top of each other anyway) and when between 480 and 768, only append two columns. So my thought is that at the different sizes, I would have to pull all of the boxes out of the columns, delete the columns, and reappend the columns in different numbers based on the window width. This has proved to be a failed attempt, so if anyone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong I would be very appreciative!

Thanks!

Comment: Just for reference, have a look at this site: http://naomiatkinson.com/ It uses a thing called Less Framework, which is an adaptive, gridularish css framework.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but if you will follow the advice then your question will no longer be of interest. ;-) 
First of all why don't you use CSS3 Media Queries for your different layouts? That is what they are for.

Secondly it is "bad practice" to use pixel values (or any other kind of absolute units) for defining breakpoints, even if a lot of authors actually do! It is best to only use relative units like 'em'.

The new Flexbox module could also be an option for you, depending on the supported Browser versions (especially IE 8).

And why don't you let the expanded box not simply overlap the other content by using 'position: absolute'?

Well, doing things with Javascript which should be done with pure CSS isn't a good idea. What happens, when JS is deactivated? And also from a performance point of view, on resizing the viewport ... - all bad.

So my advice would be to completely rethink your approach.

Comment: I definitely appreciate the advice and I would love to just do it with css3. I'm doing everything else with css media queries, however the problem lies with how css floats are handled. I don't really want the boxes to overlap when they expand to show the content, which makes position:absolute; very undesirable. My only other thought was doing it with js of some kind.

I'll check out flexbox, though! IE8 is going to be the oldest browser I support.

Comment: Some other possibilities might be:  
'display: table-cell' or 
'display: inline-block'  
(both natively supported by IE 8+)  
Floats imho aren't the best solution. ;-)  
And you also might play around with 'visibility' ...! I still do not fully understand what you exactly would like to achieve? When box is "opened" all other boxes should move downwards?